# Multiselect listView with ActionMode - how to keep selected items?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, multi-select, android-actionmode

I'm trying to create ListView with installed apps. User selects apps inside wizard (basically viewpager).

My plan is to create a list of custom views (icon, name, package) that will allow to select more than one item. Unfortunatelly checkboxes won't work, because I need this place for another functionality. So, I'll change the background of the element.

So, I found a solution on stackoverflow and changed it a bit.
Firstly - main activity with this list.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private ApplicationsAdapter applicationsAdapter;

    private void getAppList(){

        //get apps asynch
        createList(list);
    }

    private void createList(ArrayList<ApplicationItem> list){
        applicationsAdapter = new ApplicationsAdapter(this, R.layout.application_list_item, list);

        setListAdapter(applicationsAdapter);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

        getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            private int nr = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.cabselection_menu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {
                nr = 0;
                applicationsAdapter.clearSelection();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                if (checked) {
                    nr++;
                    applicationsAdapter.setNewSelection(position, checked);
                    L.d(TAG, applicationsAdapter.getItem(position).getAppName());
                } else {
                    nr--;
                    applicationsAdapter.removeSelection(position);
                }
                mode.setTitle(nr + " rows selected!");

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getAppList();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ApplicationItem item = (ApplicationItem)l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        L.d(TAG + "onListItemClick", applicationsAdapter.getItem(position).getAppName());

        l.setItemChecked(position, !applicationsAdapter.isPositionChecked(position));
    }


}
```

In my case, normally this whole thing is inside a fragment, inside the viewpager. For the sake of clarity I changed this into typical activity.

Now, the adapter:

```
public class ApplicationsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationItem> {

//    private HashMap<ApplicationItem, Boolean> objects;
private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();


public ApplicationsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ApplicationItem> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    //this.objects = objects;
}

public void setNewSelection(int position, boolean value) {
    mSelection.put(position, value);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public boolean isPositionChecked(int position) {
    Boolean result = mSelection.get(position);
    return result == null ? false : result;
}

public Set<Integer> getCurrentCheckedPosition() {
    return mSelection.keySet();
}

public void removeSelection(int position) {
    mSelection.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearSelection() {
    mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ApplicationItem getItem(int position){
    return super.getItem(position);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.application_list_item, null);
    }

    ApplicationItem item = super.getItem(position);


    if(item != null){
        TextView appName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.appName);
        TextView appPackage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.appPackage);
        ImageView appIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);

        if (appName != null){
            appName.setText(item.getAppName());
        }

        if (appPackage != null){
            appPackage.setText(item.getPackageName());
        }

        if (appIcon != null){
            appIcon.setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());
        }


    }

    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF")); //default color
    if (mSelection.get(position) != null) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);// this is a selected position so make it red
    }

    return v;
}
}
```

THE PROBLEM:
ActionMode is nice, however I'm not sure how to keep selected elements after it's destroy.
Normally inside onDestroyActionMode I'm clearing the selection. Great, so I'll just delete that. Now after clicking the "tick" symbol all apps are still selected. However, getting back to them is now problematic, because ActionMode will only "fire up" when clicking on unselected element.

So - how should I handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Ha, the answer was quite simple. I should have thought about it yesterday, but apparently I was a bit too exhausted.

First of all, I changed the mode of listview into

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

And deleted `setMultiChoiceModeListener()` and I'm only using

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ApplicationItem item = (ApplicationItem)l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    L.d(TAG + "onListItemClick", applicationsAdapter.getItem(position).getAppName());

    boolean checked = item.isSelected();

    if (!checked) {
        item.setSelected(true);
        applicationsAdapter.setNewSelection(position, checked);
        L.d(TAG, applicationsAdapter.getItem(position).getAppName());
    } else {
        item.setSelected(false);
        applicationsAdapter.removeSelection(position);
    }
}
```

That simple. 
Apparently, ActionMode may be fun, but it wasn't the right tool for this job.

And also - adapter from first post can be used as a example of multiselect listView that changes backgrounds instead of checkboxes. Apparently I couldn't find anything simple enough like that.